# Is there any possible to get access to jQuery selectors listed in JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Just like in question.

This is my object with selectors:

```
var areaToCover = {
    filters:    '.js-filtersContainer',
    list:       '.js-elementsListContainer'
};
```

and use of it:

```
areaToCover.filters.append(cover_block);
areaToCover.list.append(cover_block);
```

Is there any chance to set that kind of code? Or this is totally stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`areaToCover.filters` is a string so you can pass it to jQuery, just like a string literal

```
$(areaToCover.filters).append(cover_block)
```